# Client-Server communication with BufferedReader hanging

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm testing around with client-server communication.

I have a server that should receive messages and print them, and send messages that it gets from `System.in` using a `Socket`. The client reads messages from the `Socket`, and sends back some messages. But for some reason both the server and the client get locked when checking if there is a message from the other end (at `readLine()`).

This client:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Log.i("DataManager", "Trying to connect to server");    
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ADDRESS, PORT), 3000);
        Log.i("DataManager", "Connected to: " + socket.getInetAddress());   

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true); //autoflush

        String inputLine;
        while (socket.isConnected()) {
            if ((inputLine = in.readLine()).isEmpty()){
                Log.i("DataManager", "Server says: " + inputLine);  
            }

            synchronized (outcoming){
                if (!outcoming.isEmpty()){
                    for (int i = 0; i < outcoming.size(); i++){
                        out.println(outcoming.get(i));
                        outcoming.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } 
    ...
}//
```

The Server:

```
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    try {
        Socket socket;
        socket = listener.accept(); //waits for connection
        System.out.println("Client connected: " + socket.getInetAddress());

        BufferedReader sysRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedReader clientIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true); //autoflush

        String inputLine;
        out.println("Hello, you are connected to server" + listener.getInetAddress());
        while (true){
            if ((inputLine = clientIn.readLine()).isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Client says: " + inputLine);
            }
            String line = sysRead.readLine();
            if (line.equals("stop")){
                break;
            } else {
                out.println(line);
            }
        }
        socket.close();
    }
```

I tried solving this by encasing the `readLine` statements with `if(in.ready())` but it didn't help at all. I've been looking around on google and found that this is caused by the fact that `readLine()` looks for eof, and the stream from the socket only ends when the socket is disconnected. I have no idea how to get around this problem other that writing some kind of protocol where i end my messages with a specific sequence. Is there a better way around this problem?

Comment: Why are you only logging empty lines? NB `while (socket.isConnected())` isn't a valid test. It will never become false. You should be exiting the loop when `readLine()` returns null.

Comment: NB `readLine()` also looks for line terminators, and you're sending those. *Any* read method 'looks for EOF'. It's your logic that is at fault here, not `readLine()`.

Comment: Don't forget to invoke `flush()` when you need to flush the buffer, beside you do not follow any specific protocol/data-flow

Comment: @EJP Thats because i also want to be able to send messages, not only be stuck in a reading loop. It seemed like a good idea to stop doing both when the socket gets disconnected. I still don't see how my logic is at fault here, can you explain it? The problem occurs after the loop processes the first incoming message, it then gets stuck on the empty `BufferedReader` waiting for a new one. @user5266804 I don't need to flush the buffer because of the autoflush flag `PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)`

Comment: `Socket.isConnected()` doesn't magically becomes false when the peer disconnects. You get an EOS or an exception when that happens. You haven't answered my question about the empty line. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP I assume you mean empty lines each time i use `println()`. If i don't include empty lines, the client won't even process the welcome message, it will hang itself on `readLine()` forever, which is the problem that im trying to solve, how to make it not lock on `readLine()`. It doesn't work with empty lines and it doesn't work without the empty lines.

Comment: So the empty lines are a waste of time, and printing them ditto. Hard to see where you thought you were going with that. `readLine()` is *defined* to block until a line is received. You're using blocking I/O. You need a separate read thread.